# "npm install" not installing any library. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am using Node version `14.15.5` and npm version `6.14.11`. Also, I am working on VS Code.

I have tried to install two packages by these commands:

```
npm install express
npm install lodash
```

In the end, I am not getting any of them successfully.

I received this message:

> ```
> 36 packages are looking for funding 
>  run `npm fund` for details.
> ```

How to resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4AA2.png)

Comment: this has nothing to do with java.

Comment: I don't know why you think it installs no library. In your screenshot, Express was perfectly well installed.

Comment: actually, I want to add a library "lodash". And when it got installed it should appear in my current folder. but there is no folder of "lodash". I think this is due to funding something like that.

Comment: It's nothing to do with funding. The screenshot just fails to show you typing `npm install lodash` at all

Comment: Have you run `npm init` first to create a package.json in your current directory?

Comment: no i have not try this

Comment: i have updated the image you may check the issue there is no folder created after the command

Answer (score 0):

The reason is described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/folders#more-information):

Before installing a package into the local folder, NPM tries to find the root of your package. To do this it walks from your current directory (`C:\Users\JD Mughal\Desktop\Web\Node\test-calculator`) up the hierarchy until it finds a `package.json` file.

Only if no `package.json` file is found will NPM install the new package in the current directory (respectively in a `node_modules\package_name` subdirectory).

In your case however NPM **finds** a `package.json` file `C:\Users\JD Mughal\package.json` and installs the new package there.

To resolve the use you must execute `npm init` in your local directory.